# Break on kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL

Tags: nsurlsession, ios9, app-transport-security

I'm trying to debug an app that makes a lot of HTTP calls. I'm seeing this in the console:

```
2015-09-08 17:21:01.458 MyApp[3186:3064431] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

I understand how to add exceptions to my plist, but is there way to add a breakpoint where these requests are failing to see what is being requested?

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't able to make much of the stack trace when adding those breakpoints; however, this blog post helped me figure out which domains were failing:

http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/

tl;dr: set the environment variable CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS to 1 (how to set environment variables, if you need a hand: http://nshipster.com/launch-arguments-and-environment-variables/). this will log all the CFNetwork activity to a file that you'll see in the console; search that file for 'Did Fail' and you can see which requests are failing and why.

Comment: Did printing out $x1 not work for you? Trying to figure out if it was deterministic or not...

Comment: This is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a symbolic breakpoint in `HTTPProtocol::failWithStreamError` and/or `StrictSecurityPolicy::logInsecureLoadFailure`.

(This unfortunately may not make it easy to get the stack trace of the actual request, since this exception occurs asynchronously with the actual request creation code. But it might help you anyway.)

Comment: It looks like you can grab the URL out of register `$x1` when it breaks on `StrictSecurityPolicy::logInsecureLoadFailure`.

Comment: And in the unlikely event that you don't know where the requests are coming from, you could always add print-and-continue breakpoints on all the interesting URL-related methods (NSURLConnection's initializers and synchronous loading method, the NSURLSession*Task classes' initializers, and the NSString and NSData methods for retrieving data from a URL), print the connection object or task and the URL, wait until you hit the failure breakpoint, and then search for the URL in the resulting debug output.

Answer (score -1):

**While working with iOS 9, We have to put below lines in info.plist otherwise no any API call will work.**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
<key>dev.YourCompanyName.com</key>
<dict>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<false/>
<key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>TLSv1.2</string>
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<true/>
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>TLSv1.2</string>
<key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: That is not accurate. Some of those keys may or may not be required depending on the security of endpoint. My question is specifically about breaking on / debugging stray insecure calls. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/